# Can a SWIFT international transfer fail if I haven't provided correspondent bank information?

Tags: banking, bank-account, wire-transfer

I'm trying to withdraw money from one not scam website and it doesn't have a field for correspondent bank.

I've tried to transfer money without it but it failed and cost me $50 in fees(I sent N and got N-50 back). My bank told me to provide correspondent info - insisted, but the website told me that I can transfer without it.

The website haven't provided any reason as to why it failed and told to ask my bank. I've called my bank and they said that they haven't received anything and haven't declined anything - it failed on the other side.

So, could a transfer have failed because of the website bank not providing correspondent bank info?

I have correspondent bank account, swift and name and its intermediary bank name and SWIFT.

Comment: For better or worse, banks constantly rip you off in regards to wire transfers.  It's a case of "you're screwed".  It's **completely arbitrary**; you have no recourse.  I'd politely ask them for a refund, but it's just a case of "banks win you lose".

Comment: @JoeBlow Yeah, it's my first experience with them(banks), opening account etc. And I experience this first handedly right away :)

Comment: "Get used to it"  :)  Sorry for the bad experience.  I guess one *could* say, since they're handling money they like every detail to be perfect; so, fair enough.

Comment: If they like the details to be so perfect, they could have at least provided guides on how to fill in them and how it all works.

Comment: Believe me, I'm with you.  I often change banks (business or private) until over the years I have been "less annoyed" by one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Generally in International transfers there are 4 Banks involved. Customer's Bank [Customer who initiating the payment], also called Sender Bank. There is Sender's Correspondent Bank. Then there is Beneficiary Bank also called Receiver Bank [Bank where Beneficiary holds account]. There is Receiver's Correspondent Bank.

So Person A-> A's Bank -> A's Correspondent bank -> B's Correspondent Bank -> B's Bank -> Person B.

Depending on the currency, at times there is only one correspondent Bank. The Chain of Correspondent Bank is common knowledge and quite often if you don't provide all the details; your Bank or other Bank will fill in default details and processes the payments.

However it all depends on which bank and whether they are inclined to do so. Some bank specifically insist to use a preferred correspondent bank so if you don't specify any they may return / reject it.

Comment: The problem is, If I understood my bank correctly, they haven't rejected anything. And from the site support all I got is.. literally "Unable to apply" and that's all that they got from their bank. No more no less.

Comment: @userqwerty1 - it's completely arbitrary.  In theory they **can do it** with no information; but they're not doing it.  It's arbitrary; just another heinous bank fee.